# How to remove null values from props.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm maping from props to 'lawList', but the array contains alot of nullValues that i wish to prevent.

```
{props.map((lawList, index) => (
  <Table.Body key={index}>
    <Table.Row>
      <Table.Cell>{index + 1}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{lawList.lawDTO.name}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{lawList.text}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{lawList.status}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>
        {new Date(lawList.latestRevisionDate).toISOString().substring(0, 10)}
      </Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>placeholder</Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>
  </Table.Body>
))}
```

Any suggestions on how i can remove all null values from the 'lawList' ?

Comment: filter out all the null values before using map, like this: `props.filter(el => el).map(....)`

Comment: @MayankShukla my suggestion is to check for explicit values. `false`, empty string, 0 all are falsey. Also, it should be `!!`

Comment: btw, you shouldn't pass props as array like here

Comment: @Rajesh right, added reference of correct and proper solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter(Boolean)` on your array to filter out any falsy elements.

```
{props.lawList.filter(Boolean).map((lawList, index) => (
  <Table.Body key={index}>
    <Table.Row>
      <Table.Cell>{index + 1}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{lawList.lawDTO.name}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{lawList.text}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{lawList.status}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>
        {new Date(lawList.latestRevisionDate).toISOString().substring(0, 10)}
      </Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>placeholder</Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>
  </Table.Body>
))}
```

Comment: Stil gives me this error: https://gyazo.com/29e461ece009a48f6eaec5fefedc2feb

Comment: when i add this

   <Table.Cell>{lawList.text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"")}</Table.Cell>

Comment: @ArastoSahbaei Alright. Could you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's difficult to say what might be wrong without seeing how your data is structured. Component `props` is also an object, so the issue might be that you are trying to use `map` depending on what your `props` variable is defined as.